# Dealing with a nested firebase function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

hello I'm fairly new cloud functions and i need a little help , im trying to make a cascader that contains categories along with its subcategories but im getting the wrong response

The final response I get is the closing bracket , but after the the response is sent the categoriesList values are updated in my console log

````
    if (!verifyKey(request.get('Authorization'))) {
        response.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
        return;
    }

     var categoriesList = "[";

         db.collection("categories").get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            
            querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                let subcategories;
                let category = documentSnapshot.data();
               // console.log("id of doc -> ",`${documentSnapshot.id}`)
                db.collection("categories").doc(documentSnapshot.id).collection("subcategories").get().then(
                    querySnapshotsub=>{
                        querySnapshotsub.forEach(documentSnapshotsub=>{
                            //console.log("id of subdoc -> ",`${documentSnapshotsub.id}`)
                            subcategories=documentSnapshotsub.data().title;
                            
                            categoriesList += '["' + category.title + '","' + subcategories + '"],';
                            console.log("subcatxyz->",`${categoriesList}`)
                        })
                    }
                        
                )

                console.log("subcatss_ below ->",`${categoriesList}`)
            });

            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            response.status(500).send(stdErrorMsg);
            return;
        });
        categoriesList = categoriesList.slice(0, -1);
            categoriesList += "]";
            console.log("category cass final->",`${categoriesList}`)
            response.status(200).send(categoriesList);

}); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your asynchronous work is not properly awaited. Here's some (untested) code:

```
(async () => {

    if (!verifyKey(request.get('Authorization'))) {
        response.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
        return;
    }

    let categoriesList = "[";
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await db.collection("categories").get();
        for (const documentSnapshot of querySnapshot.docs) {
            let category = documentSnapshot.data();
            // console.log("id of doc -> ",`${documentSnapshot.id}`)
            const doc = db.collection("categories").doc(documentSnapshot.id);
            const querySnapshotsub = await doc.collection("subcategories").get();
            querySnapshotsub.forEach(documentSnapshotsub => {
                //console.log("id of subdoc -> ",`${documentSnapshotsub.id}`)
                const subTitle = documentSnapshotsub.data().title;
                categoriesList += '["' + category.title + '","' + subTitle + '"],';
                console.log("subcatxyz->", `${categoriesList}`)
            });
            console.log("subcatss_ below ->", `${categoriesList}`)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send(stdErrorMsg);
        return;
    };

    categoriesList = categoriesList.slice(0, -1);
    categoriesList += "]";
    console.log("category cass final->", `${categoriesList}`)
    response.status(200).send(categoriesList);

});
```